# fixed vs removable drive file info formats timestamp accuracy

Tags: file, filesystems, timestamp

I was writing an application to work with files on different file systems and found that the timestamp accuracy on an NTFS os drive was much more accurate than the timestamp on a removable USB flash FAT32 drive.  I am having trouble finding info on the file info timestamp accuracy for those two disk file systems in particular, does anyone know the accuracy of file system timestamps, or have pointers to where that might be found?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/127830 - two seconds on FAT, 100 ns on NTFS (no fixed vs. removable difference)

Comment: thank you tremendously, good sir, that is exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find.  you should put it in an answer

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can read at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/127830, timing accuracy is 2 seconds for FAT (12/16/32) and 100 nanoseconds for NTFS. It doesn't matter if the device is fixed or removable (nowadays I use removable NTFS frequently enough, and you can have FAT on a fixed partition if you want).